# playing video from NSData without saving a file

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, nsdata

Can any one have idea how to play video from NSData actually it's base64 String file i converted it into NSData and i want play it . without saving file in phone , directly play video from NSData...have any idea please discuss with me.

thank you.

Comment: where u get it NSData?? from url?

Comment: Why not delete the base64 string file and replace with the real data file?

Comment: actually i am getting it from base64 String file than converted it into NSData then i want without saving the file i want directally    play video..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a web player to play it，and you load the html.